# Checkbox Text going out of Screen layout

Tags: xml, android-layout, layout

I have implemented two column checkbox. But when check box text are large, it goes out of screen layout. I have attached screenshot as reference . How to restrict them to appear as multiline text and fixed inside Mobile screen. Here is my code. I have added two columns of table inside the tablel row where I have inserted the checkbox. But the text goes  outside and don't fit in same line or I want to break into two lines but should stay inside screen.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```html
 <TableLayout

                        android:layout_below="@+id/jobs_layout"
                        android:id="@+id/tableLayout_job"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:stretchColumns="0,1">

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/check_tourguide"
                                android:layout_column="0"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:checked="false"
                                android:padding="20dp"
                                android:text="TourGuide"
                                android:enabled="false"
                                android:textColor="#44f"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/check_com_op"
                                android:layout_column="1"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:checked="false"
                                android:minLines="2"
                                android:enabled="false"
                                android:padding="20dp"
                                android:text="Computer Operator"
                                android:textColor="#f44"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

                        </TableRow>


                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/check_housekeep"
                                android:layout_column="0"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:checked="false"
                                android:enabled="false"
                                android:padding="20dp"
                                android:text="House Keeping"
                                android:textColor="#44f"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/check_sales"
                                android:layout_column="1"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:checked="false"
                                android:enabled="false"
                                android:padding="20dp"
                                android:text="Sales and Marketing"
                                android:textColor="#f44"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

                        </TableRow>


                        <!--Diploma and A Level-->

                        <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/check_account"
                                android:layout_column="0"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:checked="false"
                                android:enabled="false"
                                android:padding="20dp"
                                android:text="Accountant"
                                android:textColor="#44f"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

                            <CheckBox
                                android:id="@+id/check_delivery"
                                android:layout_column="1"
                                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                android:checked="false"
                                android:enabled="false"
                                android:padding="20dp"
                                android:text="Delivery Boy"
                                android:textColor="#f44"
                                android:textSize="16sp"
                                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

                        </TableRow>
                        <!--End Diploma and A Level-->





                    </TableLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "layout_span" property in checkbox as per your requirement :

```
android:layout_span="2"
```

For eg:

```
<TableLayout
android:id="@+id/tableLayout_job"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchColumns="0,1"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_tourguide"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="TourGuide"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:textColor="#44f"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_com_op"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Computer Operator"
        android:textColor="#f44"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
</TableRow>

 <TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_housekeep"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="House Keeping"
        android:textColor="#44f"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_sales"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Sales and Marketing Department Of Organization"
        android:textColor="#f44"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:layout_span="2" />
 </TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_account"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Accountant"
        android:textColor="#44f"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_delivery"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="Delivery Boy"
        android:textColor="#f44"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
 </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

You can also see the screenshot attached
[image]

Hope this will help!